# How do I configure my Logitech Keyboard / Mouse?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, bluetooth, mouse

I have an **Mx Keys** keyboard with a *Mac & Windows* layout which I wanted to connect to my **Dell XPS** *9650* running **Elementary OS** *7 Horus*.

**First**, I had trouble connecting it to my computer.
The step by step solution was :

1. Hold the pairing button of the keyboard ( A button resembling **`1C⌑`**, **`2C⌑`** or **`3C⌑`** )
2. Click on the **`Connect`** button at the far right
3. Type in the digits shown in the displayed window
4. **Press `Enter`**

**Then** however, many special functions behind the functions keys weren't working. One example was both of the monitor brightness buttons.

> **How do I fix the special function keys actions ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using [`Solaar`](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar).
It is a Linux manager for many Logitech devices

The installation documentation can be found [**here**](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/blob/master/docs/installation.md).
I personnally chose to use pip to install the latest release of Solaar.

```
pip install --user solaar
```

After the installation process is complete, make sure you copied the udev rules as indicated in the documentation.

```
# user udev rules
sudo cp ~/.local/share/solaar/udev-rules.d/42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/

# system udev rules
sudo cp ~/.local/share/solaar/udev-rules.d/42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/
```

You might have to disconnect your devices for Solaar to recognise them.
*If you run Solaar and you haven't disconnected / reconnected your devices, the Logitech devices manager will probably tell you to do so*

However, the special function keys were still not working !

I found **two ways** to mitigate this :

#### Solution 1 : Key/Button Diversion

( my personal preference )

- Open Solaar
- Click on your keyboard in the list of devices
- Unlock the `Key/Button Diversion` setting ( press the padlock twice )
- Divert all key/button(s) you wish to redefine.
  Here is a list of those :

```
Brightness Down, Brightness Up, Mission Control/Task View, Calculator
```

- Edit rules to redefine the keys above
  To make it easier, here are the rules I used to configure those keys:

```
# ~/.config/solaar/rules.yaml
%YAML 1.3
---
- Key: [Mission Control/Task View, pressed]
- Execute: [/usr/bin/dbus-send, --session, --dest=org.pantheon.gala, --print-reply,
    /org/pantheon/gala, org.pantheon.gala.PerformAction, 'int32:1']
...
---
- Key: [Calculator, pressed]
- Execute: [/usr/bin/flatpak, run, io.elementary.calculator]
...
```

*Note that the brightness up and down keys are configured by default by Solaar, thus not showing up in the snippet above.*

Here is a link to my [**Solaar configuration**](https://github.com/alexandre-eliot/elementary-os-solaar-mx-keys-config) that you can fetch if you want to bother with the diversion and configuration step :
https://github.com/alexandre-eliot/elementary-os-solaar-mx-keys-config

#### Solution 2 : `Set OS` as `Mac OS`

- Open Solaar
- Click on your keyboard in the list of devices
- Unlock the `Set OS` setting ( press the padlock twice )
- Select `Mac OS` in the list
- Press the padlock again to lock it again

Note that, after this step, some keys may differ from the printed characters of your keyboard.
For me the `[@#|²~]` key was swapped with the `> <` key.

Also, you will have use the `opt|ctrl` key instead of the `⌘cmd|alt(gr)` to trigger the encircled symbols.

**Bonus**:

- You may want to run Solaar on Start-Up. The procedure to do so can be found [here](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/installation#running-solaar-at-startup).
- Solaar will allow you to define actions linked to key presses and other events.